# How to add icon to Self-Extracting Cabinet file in csproj file?

Tags: c#, icons, csproj, self-extracting

I have a .csproj which builds self Extracting Cabinet file. I want to assign icon to self extracting file.I am using  tag in csproj but application icon is not coming with self Extracting Cabinet file.

How i am trying :

Added Icon as Exsisting Item and make it Embedded resource 
In csproj properties -> application -> icon -set the same icon. 
and did clean build . In csproj file, name of self Extracting Cabinet file is in  tag .it is like 
selfextractingcabinetfile.one
icon.ico

now build .. selfextractingcabinetfile.one does  build but application icon does not come with that.Normal exe icon comes with it.
Any suggestion  ?

Thanks

Comment: How .csproj file looks :
<TargetName> selfextractingcabinetfile.one </TargetName>
<PropertyGroup>
       <ApplicationIcon>icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="icon.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
now build , selfextractingcabinetfile.one does builds but application icon is not  icon.ico rather it shows Normal exe icon comes with it.